# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths interfere with deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table there is two section in 1st 1 element in second 9 element exist.

insert, update, delete operation I would execute with following lines:

```
(lldb) po ipi
▿ 1 elements
  - [0] : <NSIndexPath: 0x179508a0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}

(lldb) po ipr
▿ 4 elements
  - [0] : <NSIndexPath: 0x17970810> {length = 2, path = 1 - 8}
  - [1] : <NSIndexPath: 0x17970860> {length = 2, path = 1 - 5}
  - [2] : <NSIndexPath: 0x179708b0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 2}
  - [3] : <NSIndexPath: 0x17970900> {length = 2, path = 1 - 9}

(lldb) po ipd
▿ 1 elements
  - [0] : <NSIndexPath: 0x166eadf0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

but I get a crash which says:

> attempt to delete row 9 from section 1 which only contains 9 rows
>   before the update 2015-11-23 22:20:18.969 Movie Buffs[305:25004] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 9
>   from section 1 which only contains 9 rows before the update'

Strange because {1 - 9} row I want only reload, and not delete.

Any idea what is going on?

If I comment `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` row, it does not crash.

Comment: what are the indexPaths you are trying to reload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to reload a row at index 9 when you have 9 elements. When you have 9 elements they are at index 0 through 8. There is no element at index 9. Try reloading 0-8 instead of 1-9.